# Can't preserve the value of a variable during the program

Tags: java, jsf

I have a variable(named myChoice) that I can't hold it's value during the program, this is the code.

JSF:

```
   <h:form id="main">
      <p:growl id="msgs" />
         <h:selectOneMenu value="#{Bean.myChoice}">
         <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.getMyListKPI()}" />
         <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="f1,f2,f3"
            listener="#{Bean.selectChangeHandler}"></p:ajax>
      </h:selectOneMenu>
   </h:form>
```

My code JAVA:

```
public List<SelectItem> getMyListKPI()  {
  FindKpi fkpi =new FindKpi();
   if (MyListKPI == null) {
      MyListKPI = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
           for (String val : fkpi.FindListKpi(iduser)) {
              MyListKPI.add(new SelectItem(val));
             }
             }
   return MyListKPI;
}

public void selectChangeHandler() {   //mychoice has the right value

    form1Visible = false;
    form2Visible = false;
    form3Visible = false;

    if (this.myChoice.equals("Number Of Issues in Status")) {
        this.setMyChoiceInter(myChoice);
        form1Visible = true;

    } else if (this.myChoice.equals("Response Time")) {
        form2Visible = true;
    } else if (this.myChoice.equals("Environment Availibility")) {
        form3Visible = true;
    }
}


 public String query()
 {
    if (this.myChoice.equals("Number Of Issues in Status")) {  //myChoice always NULL

     //....

   }
 }
```

UPDate

I have declared myChoice as static and it worked! :)

Comment: What is the scope of your bean?

Comment: There is a setter for `myChoice`, right?

Comment: yes there is getters and setters and the scope is request

Answer (score 0):

Simply make managed bean `Bean` (with `myChoice` property) request-scoped.